# How to resize an encrypted LVM in RAID 1 in Linux?

Tags: encryption, raid-1, lvm

I am running `3 partitions` in `RAID 1`.

```
Partition : Mountpoint : Filesystem : Encrypted : LVM
------------------------------------------------------
1         : /boot      : ext2       : No        : No
2         : /          : ext3       : Yes       : No
3         : /home      : xfs        : Yes       : Yes
```

It now happens that I have given the root of the system too few GBs; I would like to shrink the LVM (3) and give the root(2) more space. How can I do this safely without messing up the system? In what order do I have to resize the raid partitions, encryption, lvm, file systems?

Comment: What command gave you this partition display?

Answer (score 1):

There is a detailed explanation [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=4530641). I would recommend backing up your data before attempting it even if you know what you are doing just in case.